# Prove that the cartesian product of topological manifolds is again a topological manifold.

Tags: manifolds, products

I have the following problem:

> Let $I$ be a finite index set. Show that for top. manifold $M_i$ their product $M=\prod_{i\in I} M_i$ is again a top. manifold.

**Proof**
Let $(M_i,T_{M_i})_{i\in I}$ be topological manifolds. Let us consider $M=\prod_{i\in I} M_i$ with its product topology, i.e. $(M,T)$. I need to show the following three points:

1. $\forall p\in M$ there exists $U\in T$ such that $p\in U$ and $x:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow U$ is a homeomorphism. Let $p=(p_1,...p_{dim(I)})\in M$. Since $(M_i,T_{M_i})_{i\in I}$ are top. manifolds we know that all $p_k\in O_k\in T_{M_k}$ for all k. Then let us define $U=\prod_{i\in I} O_i$ then $p$ is clearly in U and $U\in T$. Furthermore we know about the existance of local charts $x_k:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow O_k$. Therefore let us define $x:\mathbb{R}^{dim(I)} \rightarrow U$ such that $x(q)=\left(x_1\left(q_1\right),...,x_{dim\left(I\right)}\left(q_{dim\left(I\right)}\right)\right)$. But since all $x_k$ are homeomorphism we know that also $x$ is a homeomorphism.
2. $T$ on M is second countable. Let us remark that all the topologies $T_{M_i}$ are second countable. I denote the basis of $T_{M_i}$ as $B_{M_i}$. Then the basis $B$ of $T$ is the union of the $B_{M_i}$, which is finite since finte intersection of finite elements are finite.
3. The topology $T$ on $M$ is Hausdorff. Let $p,q\in M$ such that $p\neq q$. Then $p_k\neq q_k$ for all k. Since $M_k$ are Hausdorff we can finde disjoint $O_k,Q_k$ such that $p_k\in O_k$ and $q_k\in Q_k$. Take $O=\prod_{k\in I} O_k$ and $Q=\prod_{k\in I} Q_k$ then $p\in O$, $q\in Q$ and $O\cap Q=\emptyset$

I'm not sure if this works and I would appreciate it if someone could take some time to discuss it.

Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but you

- use terminology which is undefined
- some of your argument are somewhat imprecise.

1. $\dim(I)$ is undefined. It certainly denotes the number of elements of $I$. You should take $I = \{1,\ldots,r\}$ and use $r$ instead of $\dim(I)$. Note that this is not the most general form a finite set, but you write $p =(p_1,\ldots, p_r)$ which shows that you *really* work with the above special case. And, by the way, $\mathbb{R}^{\dim(I)}$ does not have anything to do with that what you need.
2. You should say that $T_{M_i}$ denotes the topology on $M_i$.
3. It seems that you understand of a (local) chart on $M_i$ as a homeomorphism $\mathbb R^{m_i} \to U$, where $U \subset M_i$ is open. Note that $m_i$ is the dimension of $M_i$, you cannot work with a common $m$ as you do. Your concept of chart is somewhat unusual, the standard interpretation is that of a homeomorphism $U \to V$, where $U \subset M_i$ and $V \subset \mathbb R^{m_i}$ are open. Charts in your sense are sometimes called *local coordinate systems* (though in general one allows arbitrary open $V \subset \mathbb R^{m_i}$ as domains). Anyway, all these concepts are equivalent - but it deserves an explanation *what your interpretation is*.
4. "Since $(M_i,T_{M_i})_{i\in I}$ are top. manifolds we know that all $p_k\in O_k\in T_{M_k}$ for all k. Then let us define $U=\prod_{i\in I} O_i$ then $p$ is clearly in U and $U\in T$. Furthermore we know about the existance of local charts $x_k:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow O_k$. ..."
   In the first sentence you not tell us what the $O_i$ are. You explain it in the last sentence, and this is an illogical order. You should argue as follows:
   We know about the existence of local charts $x_k:\mathbb{R}^{m_i}\rightarrow O_k$ with $p_k \in O_k$. Let us define $U=\prod_{i\in I} O_i$. Then $p$ is clearly in U and $U\in T$. Let us define $x:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow U$ such that $x(q)=\left(x_1\left(q_1\right),...,x_r(q_r)\right)$. Here $n = \sum_{k=1}^r m_k$. But since all $x_k$ are homeomorphism we know that also $x$ is a homeomorphism.
5. "I denote the basis of $T_{M_i}$ as $B_{M_i}$. Then the basis $B$ of $T$ is the union of the $B_{M_i}$, which is finite since finte intersection of finite elements are finite." Correct it to
   Let $B_{M_i}$ be a countable basis of $T_{M_i}$. Then a basis $B$ of $T$ is given as the set of all products $\prod_i U_i$ with $U_i \in B_{M_i}$.
6. "The topology $T$ on $M$ is Hausdorff. Let $p,q\in M$ such that $p\neq q$. Then $p_k\neq q_k$ for all k. Since $M_k$ are Hausdorff we can finde disjoint $O_k,Q_k$ such that $p_k\in O_k$ and $q_k\in Q_k$. Take $O=\prod_{k\in I} O_k$ and $Q=\prod_{k\in I} Q_k$ then $p\in O$, $q\in Q$ and $O\cap Q=\emptyset$." Correct it to
   Then $p_k\neq q_k$ for **some** $k$. Since $M_k$ are Hausdorff we can finde disjoint $O_k,Q_k$ such that $p_k\in O_k$ and $q_k\in Q_k$. Take $O=\prod_{k\in I} O_k$ and $Q=\prod_{k\in I} Q_k$, where the other $O_i,Q_i$ can be chosen as arbitrary open neighborhoods of $p_i, q_i$. Then $p\in O$, $q\in Q$ and $O\cap Q=\emptyset$."

Comment: Ah wow perfect thanks, yes this explains a lot. So if I change the argumentation of my point 1, and respects all your other points then it works, so there are no more problems?

Comment: Everything okay then.

Comment: perfect thank you very much, I appreciate your help!

Comment: My point 3. is relevant only for your question in this forum. If your textbook uses your definition of chart, then there is no need to clarify it for people who work with this book. Always keep in mind to which audience you are speaking.

Comment: tis makes sense, yes in our lecture we uses this definition of local charts.

Comment: Sorry can I ask something here again?

Comment: If it is something to clarify the above question and  answer: Yes. Otherwise ask a new question.

Comment: okey so I will ask a new question, maybe you can take a look.

Comment: I postet it now

Comment: I made an update of my answer because I missed some points.

Comment: got it thank you!